# Django form fields not loading on template

Tags: python, django

The form in question won't render the form fields at all despite not raising any exceptions (which I'm assuming means the error is not a view or form error). So my question is, what else might cause such an error ? 
forms:

```
class HandInForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AssignmentsHandedIn
        fields = ['assignment', 'user_hand_in']
class ResourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form definition for File."""
    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Fileform."""

        model = Resources
        fields = ['file']
        widgets = {
            'file': forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control input"}),
        }
```

view:

```
def hand_in(request, assignment_id):
    assignment_actual = Assignments.objects.get(pk=assignment_id)
    class_assignment = assignment_actual.class_related
    if request.method == "POST":
        assignment_form = HandInForm(data=request.POST)
        resource_form = ResourceForm(data=request.POST)
        if assignment_form.is_valid() and resource_form.is_valid():
            assignment = assignment_form.save()
            assignment.user_hand_in = request.user
            assignment.assignment = assignment_actual
            resource = resource_form.save()
            resource.assignments = assignment
            resource.class_related = class_assignment
        else:
            print(assignment_form.errors, resource_form.errors)
    else:
        assignment_form = HandInForm()
        resource_form = ResourceForm()
    return render(request, "DC/handin.html", {'assignment_form': assignment_form, 'resource_form': resource_form})
```

Template:

```
    {% extends "DC/base.html" %}
    {% block body_block %}
    <br><br><br><br>
    <h1 class="titley">New Resource</h1>
    <form class="jumbotron" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Create</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');
    </script>

    {% endblock body_block %

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you name your forms `HandInForm()` `ResourceForm()` respectively:

```
assignment_form = HandInForm()
resource_form = ResourceForm()
```

However, you use the name `form` in templates

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

use instead:

```
{{ assignment_form.as_p }}

{{ resource_form.as_p }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view sends your form with different names.

`{'assignment_form': assignment_form, 'resource_form': resource_form}`

But you call form using `form`. You should use your defined name. like

`{{ assignment_form.as_p }}`, `{{ resource_form.as_p }}`